# Individual Buttons to Remove Values Entered In Datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a datalist that will contain a large number of options.  I have created a script that when a new value is entered in the data list it is shown in the HTML next to a "Remove" button which I'm not sure how to make functional.

I'm hoping for help on two things:
1)  Making the "Remove" button functional so that the individual entry is removed.
2)  When the page is loaded, grab the comma separated list (if any) from the element with id="savedvalues" and create the "Remove" button structure.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var BrowserList =[];

//When the Add Button is clicked...
$("#button").click(function(){
var selected = $("#datalistID").val();

if(selected === ''){
//Do nothing
} 
else {
BrowserList[BrowserList.length] = selected;
}

//Output the results
var EntriesAndButtons = '<ul>';
var Entries = '';
for(var i=0; i< BrowserList.length; i++) {

EntriesAndButtons += "<li>" + BrowserList[i] + " " + '<input type="button" id="removebutton" value="Remove" /></li>';
Entries += BrowserList[i] + ", ";
}

//After the loop finish the results
EntriesAndButtons += '</ul>';
CleanedEntries = Entries.slice(0,-2); //Remove the space and comma
//After the loop output the results.
$('#thelist').html(EntriesAndButtons);
$("#savedvalues").val(CleanedEntries);
});

});
</script>

<body>
Select your Test Spec:
<input list="browsers" id="datalistID">
<datalist id="browsers">
<option value="ASTM B117"></option>
<option value="ASTM B368"></option>
<option value="ASTM B467"></option>
<option value="ASTM B469"></option>
<option value="ASTM C234"></option>
<option value="ASTM C317"></option>
<option value="ASTM C456"></option>
<option value="ASTM C657"></option>
<option value="ASTM D211"></option>
<option value="ASTM D233"></option>
<option value="ASTM D334"></option>
<option value="ASTM D345"></option>
<option value="ASTM D467"></option>
<option value="ASTM D469"></option>
<option value="ASTM E234"></option>
</datalist>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Add">

<br><br>You've selected:
<p id="thelist"></p>

<br>
This text field is where the values should be stored:
<input type="text" id="savedvalues" name="browservalues" value="Chrome">
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q354797e/8/

Comment: just add: `$(document).on("click","#removebutton", function(){   $(this).parent().remove(); });` to your code, it listen to the button being clicked and because it is in the `<li>`, deleting its parent (the <li>) does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Read about [**`Event delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach event over dynamic elements.
- Iterate all `ULPARENT li` elements to get the all the `li` elements `textContent`
- Use `Array#join` to join array elements with `glue` as `,`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var BrowserList = [];
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var selected = $("#datalistID").val();
    if (selected !== '') {
      BrowserList.push(selected);
    }
    var EntriesAndButtons = '<ul id="ulParent">';
    var Entries = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < BrowserList.length; i++) {

      EntriesAndButtons += "<li>" + BrowserList[i] + " " + '<input type="button" class="removebutton" value="Remove" /></li>';
      Entries += BrowserList[i] + ", ";
    }
    EntriesAndButtons += '</ul>';
    CleanedEntries = Entries.slice(0, -2);
    $('#thelist').html(EntriesAndButtons);
    $("#savedvalues").val(CleanedEntries);
    $("#datalistID").val('');
  });
  $('#thelist').on('click', '.removebutton', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
    var val = [];
    BrowserList = [];
    $('#ulParent li').each(function() {
      val.push(this.textContent);
      BrowserList.push(this.textContent);
    });
    $("#savedvalues").val(val.join(', '));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select your Test Spec:
<input list="browsers" id="datalistID">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="ASTM B117"></option>
  <option value="ASTM B368"></option>
  <option value="ASTM B467"></option>
  <option value="ASTM B469"></option>
  <option value="ASTM C234"></option>
  <option value="ASTM C317"></option>
  <option value="ASTM C456"></option>
  <option value="ASTM C657"></option>
  <option value="ASTM D211"></option>
  <option value="ASTM D233"></option>
  <option value="ASTM D334"></option>
  <option value="ASTM D345"></option>
  <option value="ASTM D467"></option>
  <option value="ASTM D469"></option>
  <option value="ASTM E234"></option>
</datalist>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Add">

<br>
<br>You've selected:
<p id="thelist"></p>

<br>This text field is where the values should be stored:
<input type="text" id="savedvalues" name="browservalues" value="Chrome">
```

Comment: Thanks - two minor things.  1)  The removal of items doesn't seem to work because if one item is removed and then another item added the previously removed item is added back.  2)  Can the initial values taken from the text field id="savedvalues" be added to the Remove buttons list when the page is loaded?

Comment: Thank you for helping.  The addition/removal of items is now perfect.  The only thing missing is the initial addition of values from the text field id="savedvalues" (ie. Chrome + "Remove" button).  Is this a matter of running the #button.click function when the page has loaded and grab the values from the text field?

Comment: Thank again for all your help.  I made a few minor tweaks and posted the _full_ answer above.  I however want to make sure you get credit for your work so I've marked your answer as the "most helpful".

Answer (score 0):

This completed answer is posted below but it's effectively the code that Rayon posted with a couple small tweaks.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Check to see if there are any existing values
  var priorValues = $("#savedvalues").val();
  //console.log ("priorvalues is: ", priorValues);
  if (priorValues !== ''){
      //Create an array by splitting the list by comma
    var BrowserList = $('#savedvalues').val().split(",");
        createHTML();
  } else {
  var BrowserList = '';
  }

  $("#button").click(function() {
    var selected = $("#datalistID").val();
    if (selected !== '') {
      BrowserList.push(selected);
    }
    createHTML();
});
  $('#thelist').on('click', '.removebutton', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
    var val = [];
    BrowserList = [];
    $('#ulParent li').each(function() {
      val.push($.trim(this.textContent));
      BrowserList.push(this.textContent);
    //console.log ("The BrowserList value is: ", BrowserList);
    });
    $("#savedvalues").val(val.join(', '));
  });

//This function creates the HTML for the list and buttons.
function createHTML() {
   var EntriesAndButtons = '<ul id="ulParent">';
    var Entries = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < BrowserList.length; i++) {

      EntriesAndButtons += "<li>" + $.trim(BrowserList[i]) + '  <input type="button" class="removebutton" value="Remove" /></li>';

      //Trim
      Entries += $.trim(BrowserList[i]) + ", ";
    console.log ("The BrowserList value is: ", $.trim(BrowserList[i]));
    }
    EntriesAndButtons += '</ul>';
    CleanedEntries = Entries.slice(0, -2);
    $('#thelist').html(EntriesAndButtons);
    $("#savedvalues").val(CleanedEntries);
    $("#datalistID").val('');
}

});
</script>

Select your Test Spec:
<input list="browsers" id="datalistID">
<datalist id="browsers">
<option value="ASTM B117"></option>
<option value="ASTM B368"></option>
<option value="ASTM B467"></option>
<option value="ASTM B469"></option>
<option value="ASTM C234"></option>
<option value="ASTM C317"></option>
<option value="ASTM C456"></option>
<option value="ASTM C657"></option>
<option value="ASTM D211"></option>
<option value="ASTM D233"></option>
<option value="ASTM D334"></option>
<option value="ASTM D345"></option>
<option value="ASTM D467"></option>
<option value="ASTM D469"></option>
<option value="ASTM E234"></option>
</datalist>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Add">

<br><br>You've selected:
<p id="thelist"></p>

<br>
This text field is where the values should be stored:
<input type="text" id="savedvalues" name="browservalues" value="cats, dogs, horses, pigs" >
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q354797e/15/